# tts not playing when call riniging?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, telephony

when mobile is connected to earpiece and i am playing tts at call ringing it doesn't work.but as call ends it starts working i have tried setmode(mode_in_call) but it doesnt work. tts voice not routing to earpiece what can be problem. this is little bit part of problem

```
if (audio.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {

        Log.d("coming in head","********************");
        if (silent) {
            if (mode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
                if (status) {
                    if (profilt.isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
                        setcall();
                        setpitchrate();
                        speakapi();
                        return;
                    }
                }  audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                setcall();
                setpitchrate();
                speakapi();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

tts code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
 private void ttsGreater21(String text) {
     String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
     HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
     audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);
     speech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
 }
```